# UWP UART send/recieve bytes incorrectly

Tags: xamarin, uwp, uart, windows-10-iot-core

i have Pi3 and i'm developing UWP to transfer data from/to Pi3 and another device (currently PC over UART)

but i can't get the right data, i'm using the Sample from Microsoft SerialSample but it didn't work, the data comes not right, i enforced the encoding in the App in both sides but no luck.

[Link to the sample](https://github.com/ms-iot/samples/tree/develop/SerialUART)

Comment: What about your wire connections? Have your check [this tutorial](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/Samples/SerialUART.htm)?

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT Yes, that's the sample i'm using but i sent the link from github.

Comment: What USB-to-TTL cables or modules did you use?

Comment: about the cable: i'm connecting Pi3 to the PC by 2 attached cables, the first one that attached to Pi3 is 3 pins (ground, Tx and Rx) attached to a USB-to-RS232 that connected to the PC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need check [hardware compatibility list](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/docs/hardwarecompatlist) to see if your device is supported on Windows IoT core.

Also, and for serial sample [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/samples/serialuart) is a note to state the supported USB-to-TTL cables or modules:

**NOTE**: Only USB-to-TTL cables and modules with [Silicon Labs chipsets](https://www.adafruit.com/products/954) are natively supported on MinnowBoard Max and Raspberry Pi2.

So, USB-Serial CH340 is **not supported** on Windows IoT core.

For doing self testing of the device, you can use [the sample](https://github.com/ms-iot/samples/tree/develop/SerialUART) and do the following two tests :

1. First, shorten Tx and Rx of the USB-to-TTL cable to test it on PC.
2. Second, shorten Tx and Rx pins on Raspberry Pi to test its on-board UART.

You will receive what you have sent if the device works normally.

Comment: but i already getting the size of the bytes array right but the bytes itself not right, could that happened because of that? i'm not a HW person anyway and i have to get the right cables first to insure that point.

Comment: Ok. If there is any concern please feel free let me know.

Comment: Dear Rita, i bought the mentioned cable and it's working now.Thank you for your help.

Comment: Using [sample](https://github.com/ms-iot/samples/tree/develop/SerialUART), you can do the following two tests : First, shorten Tx and Rx of the USB-to-TTL cable to test it on PC. Second, shorten Tx and Rx pins on Raspberry Pi to test its on-board UART. You will receive what you have sent if the device works normally.

Comment: Yes I'm using this sample and it's working. How can I make your answer as the answer